# variable input to javascript function parameter within a JSP page

Tags: javascript, jsp, jquery-plugins

I have the following function call inside a jsp page.

```
jQuery(function($){
   $("#product").mask("99/99/9999",{placeholder:" "});
});
```

What I want to do is pass a different string into the `.mask` function. In pseudo code it would look something along the lines of:

```
String passedParam= someString  
if(test):
  passedParam = "someotherString"

jQuery(function($){
   $("#product").mask(passedParam,{placeholder:" "});
});
```

Being new to both jsp and javascript I do not know the correct way to translate this pseudo code into actual working code.

Comment: It would be more clear if you don't use a `mask` variable alongside a `mask` method. BTW, is the `mask` variable defined in JSP and further on used in the JavaScript script?

Comment: @Marcel It's fixed now. No it is not.

Comment: – Apparently it is, considering your comment on BalusC's answer. ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use taglibs/EL in JSP to print a string as if it's JavaScript code. You know, JSP runs at webserver machine, produces HTML/CSS/JS and sends it to the webbrowser which in turn starts to run JS code. You should write server side code accordingly that its HTML/CSS/JS output looks right when you're doing *View Source* in webbrowser.

Your pseudocode is a bit ambiguous, but I bet that you're looking for something like this:

```
jQuery(function($){
   $("#product").mask('${test ? 'someotherString' : mask}',{placeholder:" "});
});
```

*(don't pay attention to syntax highlighting, the code is correct, the highlighter doesn't recognize EL)*

The `${}` thing is [EL (Expression Language)](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnahq.html). It will be processed when JSP runs. It should work in template text as per Servlet 2.4/JSP 2.0 (which is already over 5 years old). The `?:` is the well known conditional operator. If the expression evaluates true, then the part after `?` will be assigned/printed (in this case the literal string `"someotherString"`), otherwise the part after the `:` (in this case the scoped variable `mask`).

This will end up in the webbrowser as

```
jQuery(function($){
   $("#product").mask('someotherString',{placeholder:" "});
});
```

or

```
jQuery(function($){
   $("#product").mask('someString',{placeholder:" "});
});
```

depending on the boolean outcome of `test`.

Answer (score 0):

Well in my jsp I would do something like this:

```
<%
String mask = someString  
if(test):
  mask = "someotherString"
%>

jQuery(function($){
   $("#product").mask(<%= mask %>,{placeholder:" "});
});
```

Comment: That's also a way, but that's pretty old fashioned. The use of scriptlets is [discouraged](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177733/howto-avoid-java-code-in-jsp-files) since over a decade. Use taglibs/EL whenever possible ;)

Answer (score 0):

Handle the mask variable using **JSP**, then put it inside **jQuery** code.

```
<%
   String mask = "";
   if (test) {
       mask = "something";
   }
   else {
       mask = "something else";
   }
%>

jQuery(function($){
   $("#product").mask('<%=mask%>',{placeholder:" "});
});
```